# What is this weird exercise given to me by my Trainer for chest?

Tags: exercise, strength, chest

My trainer told me about this exercise for the chest, but I couldn't find it on [BodyBuilding.com](https://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/finder/lookup/filter/muscle/id/1/muscle/chest)

What it involve is to have dumbbells on your sides with arm straight at initial position and then move the dumbbells to front and make them meet at shoulder height with the hands pointer upward.

What is this exercise and does it help the chest?

Comment: You may want to try a source like this instead of bodybuilding.com : http://www.exrx.net/Lists/Directory.html

Comment: If you're standing when you start the exercise, I don't see how it could work the chest.  But, it's hard to determine any of that from your description alone.

Comment: @rrirower my exact thought

Comment: Is this trainer certified?

Comment: @rrirower I hope so Its a gym in MNC company, looked like front raise for shouldier only thing was my hands were upside and i had to make dubbell meet

Comment: How can you trust his advice/training if you don't know if he's certified by a reputable organization?

Comment: @rrirower: Probably to the same degree as most of the rest of us where when the trainer rattles off where they trained, we're left wondering whether we typed the name in Google correctly? :) Or if they were actually certified by said company...

Comment: so looks like I am doing Underhand front rsie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your description could describe a [Front Raise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_raise)

> [image: Starting Front Raise Position] [image: Front Raise End]

As regards how the Front Raise can target the pectoral muscles, [this fellow comments on underhanded Front Raises](https://forum.muscleandstrength.com/threads/65782-what-do-underhand-front-raises-do?s=a9a0164c8decff86fbabb5651617ed61&p=773878&viewfull=1#post773878):

> Depending on how you do underhand front DB raises they can be for the anterior deltoid or they can be a focus on the upper peck [sic]. When bringing the palms together at the peak of the movement in front of you its a good contraction on the upper pecks. When going more straight it hits the anterior deltoids more.

Wikipedia says many of the same things in different language (bolding mine):

> It primarily works the anterior deltoid, with assistance from the serratus anterior, biceps brachii and **clavicular portions of the pectoralis major**.

Answer (score -1):

I highly advise against this.

**Biomechanically an underhand grip leads to a chain of events.**

- Supinating your forearm (palm up)
- Results in external rotation of your humerus (arm bone).
- Your deltoid (big shoulder muscle) attaches midway down on your humerus.
- Your rotator cuff - key shoulder stabilizers, attach to the head (or
  top) of your humerus.

[image]
[image]

**The Result:**

- This alters the resting position of your shoulder stabilizers so they **fire late during overhead movements**.
- Your anterior deltoid (also attached to your arm) is the primary shoulder flexor (when you raise your arm in front of you) an **increased shearing force  is applied to a now unstable joint / and rotator cuff**.
- You'll **feel this more the higher you raise your arm** (the shearing force increases).

*There’s actually a lot more going on but no need to go farther.*

Comment: is there any excercise for shoulder that is safe i have heard bad about all involving sholder

Comment: The question was "what is this exercise called" not "is this exercise safe"

Comment: I hope that's a joke.  That's like going to buying a car and asking a friend if he "likes the rims". Rather than him telling you noticed the axle is cracked,  just answering "yes I love the rims".